# How to keep the order of items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've built a form for an examination online, it displays question and answers which users can select answers, then they can submit form. This is code of my form:

```
<%= form_tag({ controller: 'exams', action: 'check_results' }, authenticity_token: true) do %>
  <ol class="questions">
    <% @questions.each do |question| %>
  <li class="content_question"><%= kramdown question.content %></li>

  <ol class="answers">
    <% question.answers.shuffle.each do |answer| %>
      <table class="answer_contents">
        <tbody>
      <tr>
        <% if question.question_type.shorcut == 'MC' %>
          <td><%= check_box_tag "user_answer_ids[#{question.id}][]", answer.id, false, id: "user_answer_ids_#{answer.id}" %></td>
          <td><li></li></td>
          <td><%= label_tag "user_answer_ids_#{answer.id}", kramdown(answer.content) %></td>
        <% else %>
          <td><%= radio_button_tag "user_answer_ids[#{question.id}][]", answer.id, false, id: "user_answer_ids_#{answer.id}" %></td>
          <td><li></li></td>
          <td><%= label_tag "user_answer_ids_#{answer.id}", kramdown(answer.content) %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
    <% end %> <%# question.answers %>
  </ol> <%# ol.answers %>
  <br>
   <% end %> <%# @questions %>
   </ol> <%# ol.questions %>
  <%= submit_tag "Finish Exam", disable_with: "Checking results...", confirm: "Are you sure?", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %> <%# form_tag %>
```

I want the order of answers is randomize, so I use:

```
<% question.answers.shuffle.each do |answer| %>
```

But with this code, the answers are random every time I refresh the page. I want the answers are random only once time, so I can review the examination later, with questions and answers are in the right order like when user do it. Anyone can give me some ideas or solutions to do it? Thanks so much.

Some models I have:

- Question has many answers
- Answer belongs to question
- Exam has many exam_questions
- Exam has many exam_answers

**ExamQuestion** model is used to store list id of questions for exam, it has some columns: `exam_id, question_id, topic_id, correct (boolean), sured (boolean)`.

**ExamAnswer** model is used to store list answer id of user, it has some columns: `exam_id, question_id, user_answer_id`

Comment: Create an array with the id of all questions and stock this array in session or cookie of user.

Comment: @JonathanTribouharet I want to review the exam of user later, with your solution if user clear session or cookie so I can not do it.

Comment: So you don't have the choice, create a table, with columns user_id, exam_id and the array which contain the order of questions in a string or in json format.

Comment: @JonathanTribouharet I had a table called **ExamQuestion** which contains exam_id, question_id (you can see in my question).  The **Exam** model had user_id, so I did not add it to ExamQuestion. The problem with me is the order of answers, not the questions.

Comment: Sorry, just add the column which contain the order of answers (in a string or json format) in ExamAnswer.

Comment: That model like answer sheet of user. So if I add column, which type is that column?

Comment: "I want the answers are random only once time" - when exactly?

Comment: @ValeryKvon I think it should at the time I create the exam. I used `exam.question_ids` to set ids of question for exam.

Comment: @KienThanh or rather at the time when you **init** the _form_ of exam? Anyway your app has to remember once-generated random sequence when form shows up. And the main question there is - once random for whom (by what)? You can do it for current user, for current session, by the time period, by specific action or anything else... If you want to random it once and **forever** - thats an another story...

Comment: @ValeryKvon A user(student) can take many exams, so I want to fix order of questions and answers in an exam, like on the paper, then I can review the exam later. Yes, I want to random it once and forever for each exam student will do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to random it once and forever:

I think you have 2 ways for this stuff:

1) To add new column to ExamQuestion: **answers_ids** containing ids of answers (random sequence). Type: ARRAY of INT. Then define :after_save callback for ExamQuestion to randomize question's answers ids into sequence. Then define :after_save and :after_destroy callbacks for answers (just to correct random sequence for all ExamQuestions existed with this answer if its being saved (created) and/or destroyed).

2) Create next dimension relationship for ExamQuestion. **ExamQuestionAnswer** belongs_to ExamQuestion, acts_as_list, :scope => :exam_question_id. Then correct your association logic.

In the view you have not the choice. Iterate not the Questions itself, but ExamQuestion object. And iterate answers according to a sequence order.

Comment: Oh man, I don't sure if you misunderstood me. I want to random position of question's answers **in each exam**. It means in different exams, question may have answers with different position. But maybe your answer give me some useful info :)

Comment: ExamAnswer model is like answer sheet on the paper, I'm thinking about add to it a answer_id column and combine with using act_as_list gem, but not sure if it can solve the problem.

Comment: @KienThanh i described two ways: one way is to order with position, other - with ids.